# Analysis of spatial replicated patterns

Tags: r, spatial, point-process

I am new to spatstat. 
I have a set of replicated patterns, I perform L test for each pattern and I pool the resulting statistic (using pool statistics in spatstat). Now I would like to perform a statistical test like dclf or mad on the pooled data, so I can make a conclusion about the population. Could you please advise me on how to perform this test?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your null hypothesis there are different things you can do.

1. To test for complete spatial randomness: Perform a dclf or mad test on each pattern separately and combine the resulting p-values like in multiple testing scenarios.
2. To test for no difference between groups: Use a permutation test (see `studpermu.test` in `spatstat` and Section 16.8.3 of "the spatstat book": *Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R*).